# compiling several dll's from same project and getting different result

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, random

Hi i am wandering how can i achieve the fallowing:
I wish to compile a project several times to several dll's and by using them from other project to get different results.
The idea behind it is to debug a reflective app.
this is my code:

```
public class MokingDataSouce : IDataSource
{
    public MokingDataSouce()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        this.MokingId = random.Next(1, 11);
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Moking Data Source " + this.MokingId; }
    }

    public int MokingId { get; set; }

    public IDocumentDetails DocumentDetails
    {
        set { }
    }
 }
```

I compile this code few times and rename dlls expecting to get different results.
when i run a program that load the dll and initiate a MokingDataSource i get same MokingId for all.

P.S i tried setting random as static member but i got the same result.

I assume it is connected to the fact the all exists in the same run time CLI. but i couldn't find a way to overcome it.

Thanks

Comment: Your random number isn't determined at compile time, and even if it were, it would still be something of a race.

Comment: i recommend a small vial of radioactive isotopes and sensor inputs as part of a RNG

Comment: @GrantThomas i am aware of that, but i assumed that different compiled code will generate different random result. but as remco mentioned in his answer its time based algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random is deterministic. It is an algorithm that generates a number for an earlier given value (the "seed").

You can initialize Random with a seed value to get the same results:

```
var rand = new Random(13);
```

When you don't specify a seed value, a time based one is used.

You are probably calling the same methods closely after one other, which is why they use the same time based seed value, resulting in the same random values.

If you want to use some value that is unique to a specific compiled version of an assembly, look into the moduleversionid of the assembly, that value is generated uniquely for each compilation:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.ModuleVersionId
```

you can do something like:

```
var rand = new Random(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule.ModuleVersionId.GetHashCode()
    );
```

to let your module generate identical random numbers, but diffrent ones for every compilation.

Comment: Wont i get the same ExecutingAssembly in my case? i don't run the dlls but load the classes reflective from a different ExecutingAssembly which is the same at execution time.

Comment: +1 for the explanation that random default algorithm is time based which explain  the identical results.

Comment: @NoamShaish: the result of 'GetExecutingAssembly' is the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx . This is not to be confused with the 'calling' assembly or the 'entry' assembly.

Comment: @NoamShaish you will need to be carefull in loading and unloading those assemblies though, since an assembly can not be actually  unloaded from an AppDomain. You will need seperate `AppDomains` in which you isolate the loaded assemblies.

Comment: could you please go into details regarding your last comment. what do you mean by separating AppDomains? and why do i need to separate them?

Comment: P.S it is working with a small fix from ModuleVersionID to ModuleVersionId

Comment: @NoamShaish : It is not possible to load two assemblies with the same strong name and major.minor version into the same appdomain.

Comment: even if i only load a class from within the assembly and not use it as an executable? i mean i just instantiate class from the assembly who implements the IDataSource interface